# How can I run and test NVENC API working on Linux CentOS?

Tags: centos, nvidia, video-encoding, gpu

We have a server with kepler graphics card and Nvidia driver already installed. How can I run `NVENC`(Hardware for Video encoding), and use its SDK on linux CentOS 6.4?

Also, how can I test if it is working in general aspects? Is there any test program, like a `NVENC` *hello world* to test `NVENC` API? Is it supported completely on Linux?

I know in the docs they said it is supported by linux but I want to know how can I use NVENC on linux and test it's functionality, you know such a command , simple code or script or step by step procedure or tutorial to getting start with NVENC API encoder to use kepler NVENC hardware on linux and in practice is it supported in all aspect in linux ?

do you have any point for running SDK sample on linux , does it need any pre-requirment or config to run ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in this [overview](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3379-High-Performance-GPU-Video-Encoding.pdf)

Also, there are a number of resources [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) including a [programming guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/NVENC_VideoEncoder_API_ProgGuide.pdf).

The SDK itself includes samples.

Yes, it's supported on Linux.

Please avail yourself of these resources and then pose more specific questions if you still need help.

Comment: Dear @Robert Crovella : I Already have seen both of this slides and even their video and reviewed NVENC AppNote and other docs.I know in the docs they said it is supported by linux but I want to know how can I use NVENC on linux and test it's functionality, you know such a command , simple code or script or step by step procedure or tutorial to getting start with NVENC API encoder to use kepler NVENC hardware on linux

Comment: Dear @Robert : do these samples in SDK run on linux too , because they are visual studio projects , I will try them by tomorrow, do u have any point for running this samples on linux ?

Comment: Take a look inside the zip file that you download from [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/nvenc/v2.0_release/nvenc_sdk_2_01_2013_0617_windows.zip).  You'll note there is a ReadMe.txt file.  I suggest you read it.  It contains instructions for "Linux Building and running the project".  Please follow those instructions.  Use the makefile in the Samples/nvEncodeApp folder.

Comment: Dear @Robert Crovella : when I make this sample on centos6.4 I get this error : /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnvidia-encode

Comment: Dear @Robert : for additional info for my error please visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684297/running-nvenc-sdk-sample-get-error-because-there-is-not-libnvidia-encode

Comment: The SDK readme indicates that an R319 or newer driver is required.  The 304.54 driver you have indicated in your other question is almost a year old and does not meet the requirements.  Please update to the latest Linux driver appropriate for your GPUs.

Comment: Dear @Robert : do you have experience in video encoding with GPU using cuda too (not NVENC hardware)? there is a windows sdk sample (cudaEncode) here http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#imaging for GPU video encoding do u know one for Linux ? please help me

Answer (score 1):

change lines in Makefile

from
LDFLAGS   += -L/usr/lib64 -lnvidia-encode -ldl

to 
LDFLAGS   += -L/usr/lib64/nvidia -lnvidia-encode -ldl

good luck !!!

Comment: While this wasn't the specific change I needed, it does seem that as of now (October 2015) The makefiles for the nvenc samples are not setting LDFLAGS correctly.