# running NVENC sdk sample get error because there is not libnvidia-encode

Tags: nvidia, video-encoding, gpu

when I want to make nvEncodeApp NVENC SDK sample on centos 6.4 I got this error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnvidia-encode
```

when I checked Make file the path to this library was here :

```
-L/usr/lib64 -lnvidia-encode -ldl
```

I checked /usr/lib64 but there is not any libnvidia-encode there:

how this library will add to this path ,whats this library ?

Using nvidia-smi should tell you that:

```
nvidia-smi 
Tue Jul 16 20:19:20 2013       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 4.304.54   Driver Version: 304.54         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     | Bus-Id        Disp.  | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage         | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  VGX K1                   | 0000:85:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   31C    P0    13W /  31W |   0%    8MB / 4095MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  VGX K1                   | 0000:86:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   39C    P0    13W /  31W |   0%    8MB / 4095MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  VGX K1                   | 0000:87:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   54C    P0    14W /  31W |   0%    8MB / 4095MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  VGX K1                   | 0000:88:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P0    14W /  31W |   0%    8MB / 4095MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   4  VGX K1                   | 0000:8B:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   31C    P0    13W /  31W |   0%    8MB / 4095MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   5  VGX K1                   | 0000:8C:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   40C    P0    14W /  31W |   0%    8MB / 4095MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   6  VGX K1                   | 0000:8D:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   59C    P0    15W /  31W |   0%    8MB / 4095MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   7  VGX K1                   | 0000:8E:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   60C    P0    14W /  31W |   0%    8MB / 4095MB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running compute processes found                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The readme files in the SDK indicate that an R319 or newer driver is required.  Your 304.54 driver as indicated by nvidia-smi is almost a year old and does not meet the requirement.  Please update to the latest linux driver for your VGX K1 GPUs [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.17-driver.html) and try again.

Comment: Yes I had noticed about that and u are right Dear Robert Crovella , how can I update my driver, my gnu is tesla k10 and for centos 6.4 : now for updating  my driver should I get my proper driver here?  http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx and install it ? if I do so it will be update with out any crash or I will have both driver ?

Comment: The 319.17 driver I linked in my answer will work. It will replace the old driver.

Comment: Dear Robert : now I could make nvEncodeApe but when I run it I get this error :                                                      NVENC error at src/CNVEncoder.cpp:1282 code=15(NVENC indicates that an invalid struct version was used by the client) "nvStatus"

Comment: for more info about runtime error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691145/nvencodeapp-successfully-make-but-in-running-it-nvenc-error-at-cnvencoder-cpp

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to create a symlink from `/usr/lib/nvidia-367/` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

```
sudo ln -sv /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libnvidia-encode.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-encode.so
```